# IFrame with runat="server" not working while upgrading the website to .net4.5.1

Tags: asp.net

We are upgrading our project from .Net2.0 to .net4.5.1.
The aspx page contains iframe tag as follows,

```
<iframe id="doc_preview" runat="server" src="" style="DISPLAY:inline; VISIBILITY:hidden"></iframe>
```

while building the project im getting the build error like "the type system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmliframe is not defined"

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the iframe to:

```
<asp:HtmlIframe id="doc_preview" runat="server" />
```

Rather than adding `runat="server"` to your iframe.

If it still throws issues then you'll want to add this to your web.config to make sure htmlcontrols are reference:

```
<controls>
 <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" assembly="System.Web"/>
</controls>
```